# ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver

Today Google chrome version has been upgraded and version is `117.0.5938.11` (Official Build) beta (64-bit). So downloaded the Chrome driver beta Version: `117.0.5938.11 (r1181205)` and when I click on Run Button in Jmeter, chrome browser is not invoking and after 1minute getting as Browser not configured.

I checked in logs getting as

```
ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler:
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try launching Chrome without JMeter or [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) from [command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) or via desktop shortcut. I'm pretty much sure that it will fail or crash. Then depending on the reason of the crash take the necessary steps for fixing it.
2. Avoid using [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Beta) versions as they might be unstable (as long as this is what you want to test)
3. If you believe that JMeter is the problem - [increase JMeter logging level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG and inspect the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.